# DateTime saved as numeric value using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, interop, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using SqlBulkCopy to save a read-only Excel sheet into a predefined SQL table.
There are several date columns in the sheet, but not all the rows have date values(empty and '#').
The corresponding columns types are varchar(20) and not smalldatetime, because otherwise I get an error that the data can not be converted.

After running SqlBulkCopy the dates are saved as numeric values in a pattern that I can't figure out.
For example:
31.12.2010 is saved as 40543
31.13.2011 is saved as 40908
30.6.2011 is saved as 40724

Now I have to present the date in web forms. The numeric values don't bother me as long as I can convert them back to date format for presenting in a GridView, but I don't know how.

Would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following:

```
DateTime.FromOADate(num).ToShortDateString();
```

where num is the numeric value of the date

Answer (score 1):

Try running this query:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(YourVarcharDateColumn AS int) AS DateTime) FROM YourTable
```

Comment: this query returns the wrong value of the date. it always deviates a few days.